# Counting tokens in a column in r

Tags: r

I have a table like this:

| ID | Strings with delimiter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A01,B02,C03 |
| 2 | A01,B02,C03,D04,E05 |
| 3 | B02, C03, D04, E05 |
| ... | ... |

Now I want to count how often a string appears in this column "strings with delimiter" and put the result again in a table like this

| String | Frequenzy |
| --- | --- |
| A01 | 2 |
| B02 | 3 |
| C03 | 3 |
| D04 | 2 |
| E05 | 2 |
| ... | ... |

Has someone an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~string,
   1L, "A01,B02,C03",
   2L, "A01,B02,C03,D04,E05",
   3L, "B02, C03, D04, E05"
  )

data %>%
  separate_rows(string) %>%
  count(string, name = "Frequency")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   string Frequency
#>   <chr>      <int>
#> 1 A01            2
#> 2 B02            3
#> 3 C03            3
#> 4 D04            2
#> 5 E05            2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>